Different Python versions for different Bazel targets?
I have many py_library, py_binary and py_test targets.
Some of these must run against 3.9.16 (constraint outside of my control) and others use 3.10.6 (in order to get more recent features).
In my WORKSPACE, I specify my toolchain:
load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "python_register_toolchains")

python_register_toolchains(
  name = "python3_9_16",
  python_version = "3.9.16",
)

load("@python3_9_16//:defs.bzl", python_interpreter = "interpreter")

# python_register_toolchains(
#   name = "python3_10_6",
#   python_version = "3.10.6",
# )

How do I tell Bazel which toolchain to use on a per-target basis?
# Not real code
py_binary(
  name = "app",
  main = "main.py",
  srcs = [
    "main.py",
  ],
  interpreter = "python3_10_6",
)


This question is about 2 vs 3: Way to use different python versions for different Bazel rules

The rules_python docs have a suggested option of specifying a specific version for specific submodules. For the per-target case, I believe you can specify the toolchain by using the toolchains attribute on the given target.
